# Closing everything while using ExecuteProcess in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros2

I use ROS 2, Python, Gazebo project. So far, I had the following code snippet to close everything (like RViz) when Gazebo was closed:

```
gazebo_exit_event_handler = RegisterEventHandler(
  event_handler=OnProcessExit(
    target_action=gazebo_node,
    on_exit=EmitEvent(event=Shutdown(reason='gazebo exited'))))
```

But now I want to switch from `Node` to `ExecuteProcess`. For example, from this:

```
gazebo_node = ExecuteProcess(
  cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', world, '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so'],
  output='screen')        
arrNodes.append(gazebo_node)
```

to this:

```
gazebo_server_process = ExecuteProcess(
  cmd=['gzserver', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_init.so', "-s", "libgazebo_ros_factory.so", world],
  output='screen')
arrNodes.append(gazebo_server_process)

gazebo_client_process = ExecuteProcess(
  cmd=['gzclient'],
  output='screen')  
arrNodes.append(gazebo_client_process)
```

and the old approach doesn't work.

is there a way to create an exit handle for something that was started with `ExecuteProcess`?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out. It works like that:

```
ExecuteProcess(
    cmd=['gzclient'],
    #cwd=[def_worlds_dir], 
    on_exit=EmitEvent(event=Shutdown(reason='gazebo client exited')),
    output='screen')
```

Full project at [robotics.snowcron.com](https://robotics.snowcron.com)